# Trivial Power of a Matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$

It is well known that $\forall A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\cdot n}: A^{0} = I $

**Proof:**

Let 
$k\in \mathbb{N},$ so $$A^{0} = A^{(k-k)}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A^{0} = A^{k} \cdot A^{-k}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A^{0} = A^{k} \cdot A^{-1 \cdot k}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A^{0} = A^{k} \cdot (A^{-1})^{k}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A^{0} = (A \cdot A^{-1})^{k}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A^{0} = (I)^{k}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A^{0} = I$$
As everybody can see $A$ must be invertable, but the statement does not requires that. Could somebody prove it for matrices that are not invertable?

Comment: It's more a definition/notational convention, it doesn't require any proof. But if you want some arguments why one would define it that way: It's obvious that $A^{n+m}= A^n\cdot A^m$ for all $n,m\geq 1$. We want to extend this rule to zero as well, hence we want that $A^{n+0}=A^n\cdot A^0=A^0\cdot A^n=A^{0+n}$, hence $A^0$ acts as the identity matrix, thus $A^0=I$.

Comment: Could you mention any strong mathematical references, where it is stated that $A^{0}=I$ is a definition

Comment: Not directly, it usually pops up when one wants to plug in matrices in polynomials, for example if $p(x)=x^3+4x$, then $p(A)=A^3+4A$. But what with $p(x)=5x+3$? We would get $p(A)=5A+3$, but that makes no sense. Hence one writes $p(x)=5x+3x^0$, then $p(A)=5A+3A^0=5A+3I$. By this convention, these types of things make sense. Normally a textbook which shows the Cayley-Hamilton theorem will have such a remark at some point.

Comment: $p(A)=5A+3$ is not defined, because in order to perform the addition of two matrices, then they must have the same typ

Comment: But you did not give me any **strong mathematical references**. You gave me only some examples they show why $A^{0} = I$ is usefull.

Comment: It could be interessting to show that a counterexample can never exist

Comment: Indeed, $5A+3$ is not defined, that's what I say. I gave you examples why it is useful and I stated where to look for remarks that make my point, namely that it is merely a convention, not something you can show, which other people here told you as well. Look for the strong mathematical references yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39528/discussion-between-ayoub-falah-and-mathematician-42).

Comment: Sorry I don't chat with strangers on the internet, not even about mathematics.

Comment: Also, see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101590/what-is-zero-power-of-a-non-square-matrix and this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixPower.html It's a definition, nothing more, just like $3^0$ is defined as $1$ and then it is compatible with the rule $3^{i+j}=3^i3^j$ for all $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$, you cannot use this rule to prove that $3^0=1$ because that requires showing this rule first which makes sense only if $3^0=1$. Why are you so against this as a definition?

Comment: First of all I did not send you any requests in order to chat with you. The system prints the message: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"

Comment: @Mathematician42 To your question. I´m not against this as a definition(I wrote you bring me **strong mathematically refereces** where it is stated that $A^0=I$ is a definition). I´m really againt weak propositions: you menstion that this is a definition, but when I required mathematical references you wrote me that I must look for it myself. That should be easy for you, because you know already that this is a definition. What I found more interessting is that you wrote me that I´m againt this mathematical fact as a definition

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $A^0 = 1$ is just a convention (i.e., it is how you *define* $A^0$), therefore it doesn't make sense to try to prove it. In order to understand this better, forget about matrices and think about abstract algebras: if $x$ is an element of such an algebra (not necessarily invertible), how would you compute $x^0$ from only knowing $x^n \ \forall n \ge 1$? You couldn't, so you *define* $x^0 = 1$. When $x$ is invertible, this is compatible with $1 = (x x^{-1})^n = x^n x^{-n} = x^{n-n} = x^0 = 1$.

Comment: $A^{0} \ne A$??

Comment: Gottlob Frege one of the most known mathematicians wrote a book "The Foundations of Arithmetic" in order to answer the question: What is the number one?(See [link](http://www.naturalthinker.net/trl/texts/Frege,Gottlob/Frege,%20Gottlob%20-%20The%20Foundations%20of%20Arithmetic%20(1953)%202Ed_%207.0-2.5%20LotB.pdf))

Comment: @AyoubFalah: That was a typo, obviously, I have corrected it. If I recall correctly, Frege's theory has been shown to be wrong - unfortunately, I cannot remember by whom, but his work is important only from a historical point of view. Anyway, it seems to me that you are wasting your time on a false problem.

Comment: $A^0 \ne 1$. It is worse than the first typo

Comment: @AyoubFalah: mathematicians often use the symbol $1$ in order to mean "the neutral element with respect to some multiplication". This means that in my first formula you should read $1$ as meaning $I$. This is a general notational custom in algebra, you should get used to it because you'll encounter it very often if you decide to study algebra.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
In your proof you assumed that $A^{n+1} = A\cdot A^n$. Then
$$A^1 = A \cdot A^0$$ but $A^1 = A$, so you have $$A = A \cdot A^0$$ or equivalently, $$0 = A - A \cdot A^0 = A \left(I - A^0\right)$$

Comment: In order to proof a statement, it is not allowed to use it in the proof process. Statements that are based on it are also not allowed (proof theory)

Comment: He says that if you assume that $A^{n+0}=A^nA^0$, then you can show it, read my comment as well.

Comment: If think it is clear for you the difference between "you assumed" and "if you assume"

Comment: @AyoubFalah i don't understand your comments. In your own argument in the question for invertible matrices you assumed that $A^{n+m} = A^m A^n$, why cannot I have the same assumption?

Comment: My comment reffered to  @Mathematician42

Comment: @AyoubFalah i still don't understand. My phrase *you assumed...* indicated that I will be assuming the same, exactly as Mathematician42 understood it.

Comment: $A - A \cdot A^0 \ne 0$, but rather  $A - A \cdot A^0 = 0_{n,n}$

Comment: $A - A \cdot A^0 = 0_{n,n}$ is a good point. What happens next?

Comment: @AyoubFalah next is more tricky. If columns of $A$ are linearly independent, this implies $0 = I - A^0$ as desired. If not, the columns of $I-A^0$ must be in the nullspace of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about $A$ being invertible. Your argument is circular: it uses that $A^{-k}=(A^{-1})^k$, and that $A^{m+n}=A^mA^n$; how would you "prove" those facts without using that $A^0=I$?

Even with numbers, that the zeroth power is the identity is a definition. What happens is that, for positive integers $m$ and $n$ one has this very nice property
$$
A^{m+n}=A^mA^n
$$
and then one uses the idea of the property to define $A^0$, and then $A^{k}$ for $k$ negative.

The definition $A^0=I$ is inspired by the fact that for numbers it makes sense to define $a^0=1$. It is not something you can deduce.